# Convert JSON to CSV with jq

Tags: json, linux, bash, csv, jq

I'm trying to extract the `sids, ll, state, name, smry` values in my `JSON` file using `jq` and export to a csv.

**JSON File (out.json):**

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "meta": {
                "uid": 74529,
                "ll": [
                    -66.9333,
                    47.0667
                ],
                "sids": [
                    "CA008102500 6"
                ],
                "state": "NB",
                "elev": 1250,
                "name": "LONG LAKE"
            },
            "smry": [
                [
                    "42",
                    "1955-02-23"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "meta": {
                "uid": 74534,
                "ll": [
                    -67.2333,
                    45.9667
                ],
                "sids": [
                    "CA008103425 6"
                ],
                "state": "NB",
                "elev": 150.9,
                "name": "NACKAWIC"
            },
            "smry": [
                [
                    "40",
                    "1969-02-23"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "meta": {
                "uid": 74549,
                "ll": [
                    -67.4667,
                    47.4667
                ],
                "sids": [
                    "CA008104933 6"
                ],
                "state": "NB",
                "elev": 794,
                "name": "ST QUENTIN"
            },
            "smry": [
                [
                    "M",
                    "M"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "meta": {
                "uid": 74550,
                "ll": [
                    -67.2667,
                    45.1833
                ],
                "sids": [
                    "CA008104936 6"
                ],
                "state": "NB",
                "elev": 36.1,
                "name": "ST STEPHEN"
            },
            "smry": [
                [
                    "48",
                    "1900-02-23"
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "meta": {
                "uid": 74554,
                "ll": [
                    -67.25,
                    47.2667
                ],
                "sids": [
                    "CA008105000 6"
                ],
                "state": "NB",
                "elev": 915.4,
                "name": "SISSON DAM"
            },
            "smry": [
                [
                    "35",
                    "1955-02-23"
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Terminal Code:**

```
jq '.data | [ {sids, ll, state, name, smry} ]' out.json
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
assertion "cb == jq_util_input_next_input_cb" failed: file "/usr/src/ports/jq/jq-1.5-3.x86_64/src/jq-1.5/util.c", line 371, function: jq_util_input_get_position
Aborted (core dumped)
```

**Example Expected Output:**

```
sids, ll, state, name, smry
CA008102500, -66.9333, 47.0667, NB, LONG LAKE, 42,1955-02-23
CA008103425, -67.2333, 45.9667, NB, NACKAWIC, 35,1955-02-23
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a lot of structure in the JSON you are ignoring with your attempt. You may be using an old version of `jq`, though; I get a simple error `jq: error (at tmp.json:6): Cannot index array with string "sids"` instead of a core dump.

Comment: Hi @chepner! I'm not very familiar with `json` but, I have recognized the complex tree structure of the file.

Comment: @arnpry: Something to get you started, `jq --raw-output '.data[] | .meta | "\(.sids) \(.ll) \(.state) \(.name)"'`, gives the values, but I don't have enough knowledge to flatten the array.

Comment: If any program dumps its core and you're able to reproduce it, then the program is doing something wrong, not you. You should report the bug upstream.

Comment: @rindeal The core dump does not occur in `jq` 1.5; if there is a bug, it's been fixed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a bit more complex because you need to flatten `sids`, `ll` and `smry` before you can flatten the whole record. I recommend to create a `jq` file:

*foo.jq*:

```
.data[]|{
    "sids":(.meta.sids[0]|split(" ")[0]),
    "ll":(.meta.ll|map(tostring)|join(",")),
    "state":.meta.state,
    "name":.meta.name,
    "smry":(.smry[]|join(","))
}|join(",")
# or, for robust csv output
# } | @csv
```

And then call:

```
jq -rf foo.jq file.json
```

Output:

```
CA008102500,-66.9333,47.0667,NB,LONG LAKE,42,1955-02-23
CA008103425,-67.2333,45.9667,NB,NACKAWIC,40,1969-02-23
CA008104933,-67.4667,47.4667,NB,ST QUENTIN,M,M
CA008104936,-67.2667,45.1833,NB,ST STEPHEN,48,1900-02-23
CA008105000,-67.25,47.2667,NB,SISSON DAM,35,1955-02-23
```

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to do! Getting the following error though: "jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:

jq: 1 compile error"

Comment: Can't really believe that. You made sure that you copied the command correctly?

Comment: Whoops! I created the file using Notepad++ and when I saved the file, the EOL Conversion was set to Windows (which adds extra line breaks), not Unix.

Comment: Using `join(",")` handles corner cases poorly compared to `@csv`

Comment: @CharlesDuffy True. But `join(",")` is imo good for non corner cases since your can easily pipe to `awk -F,`. But yeah, in a robust script I would use `@csv`